# How to Upload PHP page to Cpanel & how can we access it

Tags: php, cpanel

I want to upload PHP Page in Cpanel How can i upload the page to the Cpanel and how can i access it.

I tried using Cpanel file manager for uploading the same

Answer (score 1):

Using cPanel follow these steps:

1. Login to cPanel
2. Click on File Manager
3. Select Web Root (public_html/www) and click on Go.
   Click on Upload on the top.
   Click on Choose File to select the file which you have upload---Please convert all file in gzip, so that you can upload all files in single upload and then extract.
   You can also upload individual file.

For database:

1.Click on phpMyAdmin on the home page of your cpanel.

2. Select the database which you have used on the left side of your phpMyAdmin interface.
3. Click on SQL and paste your MySql code on it.
4. Click go to run the code.